# Did Third Party Softwares in server affects the deployed Project's Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu, exception, jsf-1.2

I am using `JSF 1.2` , `Richfaces 3.3.3` with Tomcat 6 in Ubuntu 32 bit server.
In my server Kasperskey anti virus is installed.If the antivirus is enabled in server, there are some exceptions like `Illegal Argument Exception`, `Duplicate Id Exception` etc in client machine.

According to my knowledge, these third party softwares minimises the performance of MySQL server and the fetching data from database is slow. At that time, if any `reRender` or some `AJAX` requests performs it may lead to exception.

I may be wrong. Suggest me to get clear knowledge about I mentioned above.

Comment: I imagine your anti-virus software would be checking traffic going between your server and the database server, hence the performance impact.

Comment: @Martin Bean : What can I do for that sir. These exceptions are occurred often and hence my project's quality is degraded.

Comment: Any software needs CPU and Memory to execute (During that time your application won't get cpu). if your application doesn't get cpu/memory it will respond slowly. Of course this will impact your app. performance. If you can bear that then its fine otherwise remove it.

Comment: @Kannan Set up rules in your antivirus software to not check traffic to/from your database server is speed is of more concern than security.

Comment: Please try to capture and display the AJAX statement that causes the exceptions -- _after_ it is received.  I suspect that Kasperskey is "protecting" you from hacked AJAX, but in the process screwing it up.

Comment: @Rick James. Is there any way to capture and display the AJAX statement which causes exception. I have done this by "Sysout" statements in bean methods called from AJAX event but the exception breaks the flow and i can't get.

Comment: Maybe the recipient of the AJAX call can write to the web server's log file?  (PHP has `error_log()`)